# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException : timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android, canvas, garbage-collection, timeoutexception

There is lot of questions on the site similar to my question. but none of them provides exact solution to problem.

I am developing one application which have huge amount of imageviews in one activity and I am drawing lines using canvas.

in onDestroy method , I am traversing through each element of an xml and if its an imageview I am removing its background by calling `setBackgroundResource()` and `setImageResource()` method. and drawing lines around edges of an imageview using path to make it feel like a square progressbar. 
my code calls this class maximum 20 times a second. and in that code I am creating a maximum of 5 new Paths object and drawing a line for each call.

tested application in several devices of different configuration. it runs well without any crash. but crash analytics reports an issue without much detail in it.

`android.graphics.Path.finalize()` **timed out after 10 seconds**
`android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize()` **timed out after 10 seconds**
`android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.finalize()` **timed out after 10 seconds**

these two same crashes on different object.
I have tried to figure out problem in my code but it didn't help me because there is not much details in crash logs and even on internet.
all I learnt about this issue is it is caused by Garbage Collector pauses. if application is in background this issue may arise.
there was several calls of `System.gc()` in my application , I removed all those but crash is not reproducible here in my environment , I can't test it too.

what might be causing this issue? is it `System.gc()` calls that causes this issue or the path object that I'm creating for progressbar.

Comment: did you finf any solution?